# Request and session in Servlet

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, servlets

I have very simple question with request and session in web. When I requested a same page page for multiple time from same browser with different tabs or through new window,  session ID and session creation time was same.

This I have done from internet explorer. But when in use a different browser like google chrome and access the same page then different session id and session creation time was there. As far as my understanding says http request is stateless.

So, in my case it does not seem to be stateless within same browser as for different http request new thread is created  by creating new servlet by container. So I have come to following conclusion:

If request is send from same browser with different tabs opened or through another new window at that time, the request always use the same thread for servlet operation with same session Id. If request is send from different browser then new http request is sent with new session ID.So,my question is  then when it is stateless? If the request is send concurrently from different browser? If i  declare  `scope="request">` and  `scope="session">` in spring then it also follows the same case ? If I am wrong in my understanding please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

When your server application starts a new session, the servlet container sends a `Set-Cookie` header with a `JSESSIONID` back to the browser. The browser saves that cookie, and sends it back to the server with each request regardless of what tab you are making the request from. Obvoiusly other browsers don't have access to that cookie, so they will receive another one from the server.

When your server receives a request with a `JSESSIONID` cookie, it can correlate that request with requests with the same id made earlier. The serlvet container is able to associate different attributes with that id, and persist these attributes between requests. The http session object is basically a container for these attributes, to which your server application has a read/write access. Basically this is how statefullness is implemented with http sessions on top of the otherwise stateless http protocol.

As for the threads: each request can be processed by any random thread, because the session data is not bound to a particular thread. It is the servlet container that maintains the mapping from session id to the session object containing the different attributes. Consequently any random thread can access the session object belonging to the current request based on its session id.

In Spring, `request` scope means that a bean instance gets newly created for each request, while the lifecycle of the `session` scoped beans is bound to that of the http session.

Answer (score 1):

**Spring**

```
scope="request"
```

Creates new instance of bean per request.

```
 scope="session"
```

Creates new instance of bean per session.And maintains instance of bean throughout the session life-cycle

[Refer this for better understanding](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of browsers, Http protocol is stateless. State-fullness is implemented via cookies and session.

When request is sent from the browser, servers creates session and sends back a unique id to the client. And the client uses this id(Cookie) in subsequent request so that server could identify request and associate it with the session.

As far as requests are concerned, server creates separate thread to handle each request irrespective of window, tab or browser. However there will be only one session created per browser.

Note: Latest browsers share the session and the request made from tab, or new window will use the same session. Ex latest IE releases IE7, IE8 and IE9 are well know as Loosely-Coupled IE (LCIE). check this for more details [LCIE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx)