# JSP Continuos Scrolling Storing page variables in a session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, pagination

I am have a currently working continuous scrolling pagination,since Http is stateless and there's no way to get back the previous data set from the HttpRequest , is it a good practice to store page variables into a user session? (like adding the id of the last content loaded so that on the next load or next request it would load the next element to it)(Assuming the page are loaded via AJAX) I have implemented it like this.

So for example, if the user search a certain name it would go to a certain action that would perform this.

```
paginationHelperBean = new PaginationHelper();

        if(page == 0 && name != null){
            paginationHelperBean.setCurrent_page(0);
        } else {
            paginationHelperBean.setCurrent_page(page);
        }

        //Set the paginationBean for display references in JSP later
        paginationHelperBean.setPer_page(RESULTS_PER_PAGE);
        paginationHelperBean.setTotal_count(profileService.countSearchProfiles(name, paginationHelperBean.getCurrent_page(), RESULTS_PER_PAGE));
        paginationHelperBean.setNumber_of_pages();


    session.put("profileSearchKey", this.name);
    session.put("profileSearchPage", page);
```

and when the user request for another fragment or data set it would the next item from the previously loaded content it would execute action that does this.

```
String key = (String)session.get("profileSearchKey");

int page = (Integer)session.get("profileSearchPage")+1;
profiles = profileService.searchProfiles(key, page, RESULTS_PER_PAGE);
session.put("profileSearchPage", page);
```

So my question is, is it a bad practice to store page related variables in a Session for pagination(eg Search pagination with continuous scrolling?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion doing infinite scrolling should be no different than using any ajax call to fetch additional content, you have something that triggers the fetch of additional data (the user scrolling to the bottom of the page) and when it arrives you display it. Also, you can update a JavaScript variable with the last page number fetched so that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page again, you fetch the next page (no need to store this information in a session variable, e.g. ajax call to /nextPage.jsp?page_number=[valueFromJavaSript]).

Contrast this with storing the last page fetched in a session variable. Imagine your user navigates away from the infinite scrolling page and comes back, what do you expect should happen?  Have the jsp page reset the session variable for page number when you navigate back to it, so that subsequent ajax calls fetch the right page number. 
Also, if you add more than one infinite scrolling page you'll have several "current pages" stored in session.

I wanted to check how other people are doing it before I submitted my answer, I'm pretty sure that Slashdot used to have infinite scrolling, unfortunately it has a next button now. But I found an article "30+ Great Examples of Infinite Scrolling Websites" [here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/04/30-infinite-scrolling-websites.html). I used fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check if they were passing the page number in the request (i.e. not storing it in session), and the ones I checked are (either page number, offset, or something similar, but the information is clearly going in the request).

Answer (score 0):

is it a good practice to store page variables into a user session:No.As session attributes is not thread safe .AS it is accessible to only those with access to specific HttpSession.For better see [Request and session in Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131210/request-and-session-in-servlet)

The code you have written can pass through sychnonization issue.In the case when one  thread is getting the value that it has set previously there will be chance that another thread has modified and set different value .So when first thread tries to get value though it may get value but it might not be right value.
The code 
    session.put("profileSearchKey", this.name);
    session.put("profileSearchPage", page);
   suppose  thread A put value for profileSearchKey and profileSearchPage.When  thread A tries to get value for attribute name profileSearchKey and profileSearchPage the value of this.name and page may be modified by another thread.So,on getting value there synchronization issue will arrive.